# counting trackbacks, pingbacks and comments of a post

Tags: comments, count, pingbacks

I wish to display the number of `trackbacks`, `pingbacks` and `comments` a post has. I've read all about them and I am wondering if there is a simple solution, that I am not seeing, available.

I know that [`wp_count_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_count_comments) ([trac line 1188](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1188)) searches in WPs cache before making a database query and I want to know if there is such a thing for **pingbacks** and **trackbacks**.

Right now I am using this [**modified code**](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/comment/count-comments-trackbacks-and-pingbacks/) to show the number of comments, trackbacks, pingbacks and pings(trackbacks + pingbacks)

```
function commentCount( $type = 'pings' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $type == 'pings' ) {
        $typeSql = 'comment_type != ""';
    } elseif ( $type == 'trackbacks' ) {
        $typeSql = 'comment_type = "trackback"';
    } elseif ( $type == 'pingbacks' ) {
        $typeSql = 'comment_type = "pingback"';
    }

    $result = $wpdb->get_var( '
        SELECT
            COUNT(comment_ID)
        FROM
            ' . $wpdb->comments . '
        WHERE
            ' . $typeSql . ' AND
            comment_approved="1" AND
            comment_post_ID= ' . get_the_ID()
    );

    return $result;
}


$comments   = wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() );
$trackbacks = commentCount( 'trackbacks' );
$pingbacks  = commentCount( 'trackbacks' );
$pings      = commentCount( 'pings' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_comments).

In the `type` parameter you can pass the type of comment (trackback, ping), you can filter by status, and you have a parameter called `count`, that when is set to `true` returns just the number of comments that match the parameters you passed.

```
 get_comments(
    array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id'=> get_the_ID(), 
    'type'=> 'pings', 
    'count' => true)
 );
```

This example gets the number of approved pings for a post, you have to use it inside a loop, if not, the function `get_the_ID()` wont work, but you just have to pass the ID as you want.

Comment: And after just `echo $var;`, right?

Comment: yes, check the result, as if it's zero instead of showing "0 pingbacks", just don't show anything, but that is a design decision you have to make.